# Can I ignore this nuget warning about no API KEY?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, artifactory

When pushing I see this:

```
nuget push blah.1.0.0.nupkg -source repo
WARNING: No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'https://meeee.jfrog.io/meeee/api/nuget/repo'. To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
Pushing blah.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://meeee.jfrog.io/meeeee/api/nuget/repo'...
  PUT https://meeee.jfrog.io/meeee/api/nuget/repo/
  Created https://meeee.jfrog.io/meeee/api/nuget/repo/ 8585ms
```

Still works and it has to be using the API key because otherwise I'd get access denied - so I'm not sure what it's warning me about. Maybe because I don't have a default machine wide API key? I had to add the nuget source with user name and password because nuget is a mess and won't pull the default API key for it without setting it for each source.

Also I noticed even if I upload the same exact package a bunch of times in a row it still uploads it - I thought maybe Artifactory would see it was the same and not upload or tell me that?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have your credentials specified in your `nuget.config` file for `repo` to authenticate.

To get rid of the warning, simply specify a dummy API key using --api-key 0 in your request.

**Edit 2023-09-13**: with a recent update, this no longer appears to work as stated by @Petter Hesselberg

Comment: This got rid of the warning for us, but following a GitLab upgrade (on-prem 16.3) we started getting 400 (Bad Request) returns from `dotnet nuget push`.  Passing `--api-key $CI_JOB_TOKEN` instead of ` --api-key 0` fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

The warning went away for me after using the following nuget command:

```
nuget setapikey YOUR_API_KEY -source YOUR_SOURCE_NAME
```

Comment: That does not answer the question.